# how do i change the increase of ++ operator (plus plus) in java

Tags: java

I am working on a small game. In this game objects are falling towards you which you have to dodge. As time passes by, the objects are moving faster towards you the make the game more difficult.

My problem is: if I use the ++ operator as in speed ++ then the objects are going too fast in a too short time period.

Lets say we have this default code:

```
int speed = 1;
speed ++
```

So I need something (maybe deltatimer?) to manipulate the ++ operator and also give it a maximum value.

Comment: You can't change how `++` works since `speed++` in your case simply represents `speed = speed + 1`. What you may want to do, is add conditions when `++` should be used, or maybe recalculate its value based on time like in every minute increase speed but only if it is not greater than some max value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want a slower linear progression and can handle decimals:

```
double increment = 0.2;  // or whatever value you like
double speed = 1;
// ...
speed += increment;
```

Perhaps you want a slower growth curve:

```
int speed_stepper = 2;
double speed = 1;
// ...
speed = 2 * Math.log(speed_stepper ++);
```

Here's how these growth curves look (courtesy of [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%2C+x*0.2%2C+2+*+log+x%29%2C+x%3D0..20)):

[image: growth curves]

To set a maximum, just add a comparison at the end:

```
if (speed > maximum) { speed = maximum; }
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped me out but how do I set a maximum?

Comment: I got it like this: speed += increment;
                         double maximum = 4;
                         if (speed > maximum) { speed = maximum; } 

But it doesn't stop at 4

Comment: If speed is an `int` then you may have difficulties assigning its value to a `double`. it otherwise looks fine to me, but my Java is rusty.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is: if I use the ++ operator as in speed ++ then the
>   objects are going too fast in a too short time period.

Then `++` is not how you want to increment.  What's wrong with something like :

```
xPosition += DELTA_X;
yPosition += DELTA_Y;
```

Also, using `++` will not facilitate variable speed (*it always assumes speed = 1*), whereas the above approach does.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are incrementing your speed variable too often. If you want your variable to increment after specified period of time you can use Timer and TimerTask classes. Example:

```
timer = new Timer(true);

TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        speed++;
    }
};

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 10000); // runs timerTask every 10000ms (10 seconds)
```

this code basically increments speed by 1 every 10 seconds
. So if you have speed = 1 at the beggining you will have speed = 6 after 50 seconds.

I think you might also use float value instead of int for speed and increment it with small values like 0.1 ex.

```
float speed = 1.0f;
speed+=0.1f;
```